# Pushing notifications from a Django app with one server process

Tags: python, django, websocket, tornado, gevent-socketio

I have a Django app served by Gunicorn.
I want to add WebSocket notifications to it, using PostgreSQL as the message queue and either *gevent-socketio* or *tornadio* as the WebSocket server.

**Can I use the same Gunicorn process to serve WebSockets? Or, rather, do I need another process running gevent's `SocketIOServer` or tornadio's `SocketServer`?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can for example use [gevent-socketio with Django](http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/server_integration.html?highlight=django#django-runserver) and have only one process running for all requests. Per default the socket-io requests go to `/socket.io/` - you could even use the same urls for socketio-requests as well as for others, but it makes sense to keep them in a sub-path (eg. for proxy configurations).

But nonetheless it might make sense to have a seperate process for serving normal HTTP requests (eg. some easy load-balancing etc...).

Comment: And no special configuration will be needed for Gunicorn?